# Query 3 tables with filters on them

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables: orders, products and suppliers which are related to each other.

I want to list the orders, the products from orders and for each product the product suppliers.

My problem is when I apply a filter on suppliers, if the return is 0, i don't want to list the product who have no suppliers after filtering and the same thing I want for the orders that have no products, not to display them.

My tables structures are this:

```
OrderId    | OrderName    | OrderPrice   | OrderStatus
ProductId  | orderIdRef   | ProductName  | ProductPrice 
SupplierId | productIdRef | SupplierName | SupplierPrice
```

Thank you!

Comment: what have you done so far? show your query

Comment: your data struct is not clear  .. please update your question adding a clear (table related) struc a proper data sample , and the expected  result

Comment: Mention the DB as well as sample dataset with proper DDL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, then you want list of all orders which have products against them which in turn have suppliers against them post filtering.
A simple join would solve your issue.

```
WITH order_set AS
     (SELECT 1 orderid, 'O1' ordername, 2000 orderprice, 'Open' orderstatus
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 2 orderid, 'O2' ordername, 4000 orderprice, 'Closed' orderstatus
        FROM DUAL),
     prod_set AS
     (SELECT '11' productid, '1' orderidref, 'P1' productname,
             10 productprice
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '12' productid, '1' orderidref, 'P2' productname,
             10 productprice
        FROM DUAL),
     supp_set AS
     (SELECT '111' supplierid, '11' productidref, 'S1' suppliername,
             100 supplierprice
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '112' supplierid, '11' productidref, 'S2' suppliername,
             200 supplierprice
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM order_set JOIN prod_set ON (orderid = orderidref)
       JOIN supp_set ON (productid = productidref)
 WHERE filter_condition;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, I will test it and get back.